# Execute process task not running from SQL Agent Job

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-agent-job

I have an SSIS package that runs a backup in a T-SQL task and then uploads the file to google drive from an execute process task. The package runs perfectly from the catalog. When I try to run it from sql-agent job, the backup runs ok but the upload to google drive does not. There are no error messages in the job history or in the package history.

The sql agent job is set to run from a proxy account with the necessary credentials.

Answer (score 0):

The issue turned out to be that the command file was trying to find another file it needed to run execute the code, but since the windows user changed it was looking in a different users folder. We solved it by passing the filepath as a param so it doesn't default to the user accounts folder its executed from.